# Firebase not returning data

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following swift code for retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database:

```
    private let db = Database.database().reference(withPath: "food")

    func fetchFoods() {
        db.getData(completion: { error, snapshot in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("ERROR")
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print(snapshot.value as? String ?? "Unknown")
            // Food data is stored as a map of UUIDs to Food objects
            guard let foodDicts = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("ERROR: type cast failed")
                return
            }
        })
    }
```

But I am having a strange problem where if my data is stored as such:

```
{
  "food": [{
      "id": "8466A419-AE6E-4997-BE74-220B59C95F96",
      "cholestrol": 0,
      "macroProfile": {
        "carbProfile": {
          "sugar": 0,
          "fiber": 0
        },
      ...
  }]
}
```

There are no problems retrieving the data. However, if the data is stored as such:

```
{
  "food": {
      "8466A419-AE6E-4997-BE74-220B59C95F96": {
        "cholestrol": 0,
        "macroProfile": {
          "carbProfile": {
            "sugar": 0,
            "fiber": 0
          },
        ...
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting:

```
Unable to get latest value for query FQuerySpec (path: /, params: {
}), client offline with no active listeners and no matching disk cache entries
```

Comment: Show your dataset tree as an image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by editing `database.rules.json` and setting read and write rules to true.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Now why was the other data format working, you might ask? Because it was cached from before!! And somewhere along the way my rules file got changed.